# Magento2 : Quantity filter not working properly in product grid

Tags: filter, magento-2.1.7, product-grid

In magento2 admin panel, I want to filter all product which have quantity `zero` or `no (empty/blank)` value.

But when I filter by quantity `from` 0 `to` 0 then, it is returning all products.

When I filter from `0.00` to `0.00` then it is returning products with `zero` quantity.

But it should not happen.

What should I do so that if I enter `zero` in `from` and `to` field then it return all products with `out of stock`?